# Check front flash available using camera2 API

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I'm testing my camera app on Samsung J7 Pro which have **front flash** (real hardware LED flash). When I'm checking **front flash** available with the deprecated [Camera API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) using:

```
List<String> supportFlashModes = defaultParameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
boolean isSupportedFlashMode = (supportFlashModes != null && supportFlashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON));
```

it works properly, the supported flash modes return 4 values (on, off, auto_flash, always_flash) for front camera.

But when I'm checking with the new [Camera2 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) using:

```
Boolean b = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
boolean isSupportedFlashMode = b != null ? b : false;
```

`isSupportedFlashMode` always return `false` for front camera. And if I check the supported flash modes using:

```
characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_MODES);
```

it's also return only 2 values (ae_on, ae_off).

Does anyone know how to solve this? Note that I've just want to check the availability of device's **front flash** Thank you.

**Update**

These methods **worked fine** on my Q-Mobile device (which also have a real LED front flash), but still not working on Samsung J7 Pro. I don't know why?

Comment: null cannot be assign on boolean.

Comment: I am finding J7 device to answer ^^

Comment: @HemantParmar I did not get you?

Comment: what `Boolean b` is returning ?

Comment: @HemantParmar Boolean is an wrapper of `boolean`, as a normal class it can store `null` value. I use this to prevent `NullPointerException` when unboxing value got from `characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE)`

Comment: try this `for (String camId : camManager.getCameraIdList()) {

            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = camManager.getCameraCharacteristics(camId);
            Boolean hasFlash = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);}`

Comment: @HemantParmar this is nothing different from my approach. I just want to check available of **front flash**

Comment: this code working in my case, i thinks its device hardware issue.

Comment: Any body else? :(

Comment: @HemantParmar does this work for you on another J7 Pro, or you tried a different device model?

Comment: @AlexCohn did you face this problem? I don't have any other J7 pro to test it

Comment: No, I have never held this device in my hands; I had intimate relationship with many other Samsung phones, though. From my experience, it's unlikely a hardware glitch. More likely, this is a bug on device level. You can try same [characteristics](http://img-developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/sms/camera/com/samsung/android/sdk/camera/SCameraCharacteristics.html#FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE) from Samsung proprietary SCamera API.

Comment: @AlexCohn I've ready tried to use their Samsung galaxy SDK, but it built on top of camera2, and not work on my J7 pro too. I will try to borrow another J7 pro to test it tonight.

Comment: For this front camera, is `CameraCharacteristics.get(INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL) == INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY` ?

Comment: @AlexCohn No, I've already disable camera2 for device which have hardware supported level == LEGACY. :(

Comment: Another question: you receive the wrong answer when you ask camera2 if the front flash is available; but can you manipulate this flash via camera2? Or you must simply put J7Pro on the blacklist of devices that pretend to have camera2, but require the old Camera API to work reliably?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168531/discussion-between-nhoxbypass-and-alex-cohn).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seen to be a device related issues. My company app which using camera2 API also faced the same problem.

I've already try to test it with a simple sample and [OpenCamera](https://opencamera.sourceforge.io/) but none of them worked. Then I decided to hold this bug till now because the number of devices that have front flash is small and most of them worked fine.

Comment: It also happen on another J7 Pro device (which I borrowed from my friend). So may be it's device issue :(